# hazelcast-kubernetes dns lookup failed issue

Tags: openshift, kubernetes, hazelcast

I'm running my project in wildfly in a container in openshift. And I'm trying to add hazelcast-kubernetes plugin( from https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes) to my project for DNS lookup. It seems the plugin's DNS lookup doesn't work at all.

Inside the Openshift's logs, it shows the Kubernetes Discovery SPI activated and wildfly starts successfully.

I've already set my hazelcast following the instruction:

```
        this.config.setProperty("hazelcast.discovery.enabled", "true");
        this.config.setProperty("hazelcast.rest.enabled","true");
        final JoinConfig joinConfig = networkConfig.getJoin();
        joinConfig.getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
        joinConfig.getTcpIpConfig().setEnabled(false);

        final HazelcastKubernetesDiscoveryStrategyFactory factory = new HazelcastKubernetesDiscoveryStrategyFactory();

        final DiscoveryStrategyConfig strategyConfig = new DiscoveryStrategyConfig(factory);
        strategyConfig.addProperty("service-dns", "kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local"); 
        strategyConfig.addProperty("service-dns-timeout", "10");
```

Did I miss something? Any advice would be appreciate.

Comment: How many instances do you try to discover? I heard reports that the DNS discovery fails with more than 6 instances.

Comment: I have definitely more then 6. Thanks.

Comment: Can you try to see if it is the same issue?

Comment: I think the problem happened because of something else. But thanks as well!

Comment: Can you do a DNS lookup (using nslookup) inside the PODs?

Comment: Thanks @noctarius, I tried to enable peer-host-lookup flag in wildfly. It didn't workout.

Comment: Hi @noctarius, Yes, I can do nslookup and dig inside pods. Acturally, there are 2 instances. The problem is I can lookup inside pods. But I can't lookup from my java project inside wildfly image. (I'm using org.xbill.DNS.Lookup)

Comment: Sorry for the long wait, did you try to use the service lookup API based discovery? In general the DNS way seems to be pretty fragile.

Comment: So, what was the solution here? I have the same problem.